# Need to print access token using java

Tags: java, rest, post, okhttp, bearer-token

When I call below `API` from postman, it returns `access-token`.

[image]

But when I call same API from java it returns `status code`, `url` but it does not return `access token`. below is the `response` which my program prints.

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://idcs-82972921e42641b1bf08128c3d93a19c.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token}
```

Below is the code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

public class NewClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1");
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url("https://idcs-82972921e42641b1bf08128c3d93a19c.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token")
                  .method("POST", body)
                  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                  .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic aWRjcy1vZGEtOTQxN2Y5MzU2MGI5NGViOGEyZTJhNGM5YWFjOWEzZmYtdDBfQVBQSUQ6MjQ0YWU4ZTItNmY3MS00YWYyLWI1Y2MtOTExMDg5MGQxNDU2")
                  .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response);
            
    }

}
```

How can I print `Access token`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the whole response string with `System.out.println(response.body().string());`
Now you have to parse the string to a JSON object with POJO class. From POJO class, you can just print the Access token or whatever you get from API response. **You can check out [here](https://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java.html) how to convert String to a JSON object.**